# Handling non integer in inputbox in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a variable called "need" that is defined as an integer. An input box come up and prompts the user. If they type an integer it displays Msgbox "Got your number". If I type a string I get Runtime error '13': type mismatch. I thought if I just used an Else statement, it would say try again. It is not doing that though. Do I need error handling in the Else statement? And if so, what would the line(s) be?

```
Sub gadgetmanuf()

Dim need As Integer
'Dim rawneed As Single
'Dim rawavailable As Single


    need = InputBox("How many gadgets are needed?", "Insert a number")

    If TypeName(need) = "Integer" Then
        MsgBox ("Got your number")
    Else
        MsgBox ("Try again")
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using an `Application.InputBox` with type `1` forces the user to enter a number (provides its own error message for text, ranges etc). So all you need to handle is the `Cancel` option, ie

The code below uses a variant to handle this, as using `Cancel` with an *Integer* or *Long* gives 0 - which could be a valid entry.

```
Sub TaylorWalker()
redo:
vStr = Application.InputBox("How many gadgets are needed?", "Enter a number", , , , , , Type:=1)
If vStr = False Then GoTo redo
End Sub
```

*longer option*

Test that the entered variable is greater than 0

```
Sub EddieBetts()
Dim StrPrompt As String
Dim lngNum As Long

StrPrompt = "How many gadgets are needed?"
redo:
lngNum = Application.InputBox(StrPrompt, "Enter an integer number (numbers will be rounded)", , , , , , Type:=1)
If lngNum < 1 Then
    StrPrompt = "How many gadgets are needed - this must be a postive integer"
    GoTo redo
End If

MsgBox "User entered " & lngNum

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example 'need' is an integer data type so it will always be an integer.

Have a look at this:

```
Sub test()
  x = Range("A1").Value
  If Int(x) / x = 1 Then
    MsgBox "Value is an Integer"
  Else
    MsgBox "Value is not an Integer"
  End If
End Sub
```

or Assuming A1 has the number, put, in any other cell, the formula:

```
=IF(INT(A1)=A1,"True","False")
```